# #pragma once is not working in visual studio

Tags: c++

I am using visual studio and #pragma once is not working. This is the following error i get:

```
1>namespaces.obj : error LNK2005: "int a" (?a@@3HA) already defined in another.obj
1>fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

These are the files

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << a;
}
```

another.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

void hi() {
    std::cout << a;
}
```

header.h

```
#pragma once

int a = 5;
```

Answer (score 6):

`#pragma once` does not mean "include me in only one source file", it means "only include me once in a single source file.

Answer (score 2):

You should not define a global variable in a header file for exactly this reason. `#pragma once` does not protect you from this kind of error. In fact, nothing can protect you from this kind of error, because each source file is compiled **separately**. What happens in one compilation unit has no effect on what happens in another compilation unit.

The solution is to move `int a = 5;` to `main.cpp`, and change `header.h` to say `extern int a;`.